# Get cell by value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

### How do I get the range of a cell using its *value* and *column*?

Say I have this column:

```
[   ][   A   ]
[ 1 ][ hello ]
[ 2 ][ world ]
[ 3 ][ waaah ]
[ 4 ][ waaah ]
[ 5 ][ waaah ]
Sheet: WALUIGI_SAYS_"HI"
```

I want to find the first instance of `waaah`. I know it is in column `A`, but I do not know the row.

How do I find it with apps scripts?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Best to show some code you have tried, and then people will help. However, one way to to this is to put a formula like =match("waaah","A1:A5",0) in a cell an read the value of that cell it in the script.

Comment: Apologies, There was a typo in my comment above, `=match("waaah","A1:A5",0)` should read `=MATCH("waaah",A1:A5,0)`. Also I added some code samples. Let me know if OK.

Comment: @bcperth I didn't add the code I tried, because I'm pretty sure the formulas I was using had nothing to do with what I was trying to achieve. I felt that it would confuse, rather than clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways at least to do what you ask.

1. Manually put a formula like `=MATCH("waaah",A1:A5,0)` in a cell an read the value of that cell it in the script.
2. Put the formula in a cell from a script and read as above.
3. Make your own script to loop through the range, checking for a value match at each location. Increment a counter on each loop and exit the loop when a match is found. The counter will be the index.

EDIT:  Added some sample code for clarity with each method demonstrated.

```
/**
 * Finds first matching row in a column
 * @customfunction
 */
function findFirstMatchingRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Method 1 - Formula manually placed in B1
  var row = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  if (row=="#N/A"){
      Logger.log("NoMatch");  
  }else
  {
       Logger.log(row);  // shows 3
  }


  //Method 2 - Formula placed in B2 via script.
  row = sheet.getRange("B2").setFormula("=MATCH(\"waaah\",A1:A5,0)").getValue();
   if (row=="#N/A"){
      Logger.log("NoMatch");  
  }else
  {
       Logger.log(row);  // shows 3
  }

  //Method 3 - Make your own search loop
  // first load the values into an array (in one trip to the server)
  var valuesArray = sheet.getRange("A1:A5").getValues();
  var lengthOfArray = valuesArray.length;
  var matchFound = false;
  var n;

  for (n=0; n<lengthOfArray; n++){   // loop through the values looking for a match
      if (valuesArray[n] == "waaah")
      {
        matchFound=true;
        n++;                        // add one because arrays start at 0 not
        break;
      }
  }
  if (matchFound){
    Logger.log(n);    // shows 3
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("No match");
  }

}
```

Produces this log output:

```
[18-10-22 08:43:49:917 HKT] 3.0
[18-10-22 08:43:50:176 HKT] 3.0
[18-10-22 08:43:50:300 HKT] 3.0
```

Comment: `A1:A5` only works if the total amount of cells in the column is 5. I recommend correcting to `A1:A` or `A1:A1001`. 1000 is the usual sheet length on a blank google sheet

Comment: Yes of course, thanks.  In reply I was just following your example problem for clarity....I thought!